# What are these fields in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am finding these fields in SQL Server 2008 R2 but I have no idea what they are for and for example, what is the difference between bit and Flag:bit. I cannot find any documentation for it. I just found this link [Data Types](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187594%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Flag:bit
NameStyle:bit
Name:nvarchar
OrderNumber: nvarchar
Phone:nvarchar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are `Alias Data Types` and probably you found those names in AdventureWorks sample database provided by Microsoft

To get more info from Alias Data Types refer to this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189283(v=sql.100).aspx

> Alias types are based on the system data types in SQL Server. Alias
>   types can be used when several tables must store the same type of data
>   in a column and you have to make sure that these columns have
>   identical data type, length, and nullability. For example, an alias
>   type called postal_code could be created based on the char data type.
>   Alias types without rules or an attached default definition are
>   supported in table variables since SQL Server 2005. Alias types in
>   table variables are not supported in SQL Server before SQL Server
>   2005.

To know the aliases MS is using on AdventureWorks refer to this one:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124807(v=sql.100).aspx

The following table lists alias data types, the Transact-SQL user-defined data types, and the tables and columns that use them

[image]

From [technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com)